# How do I find a group of words using Reg-ex?

Tags: java, regex

Here is the code:

```
String Str ="Animals \n" +
                "Dog \n" +
                "Cat \n" +
            "Fruits \n" +
                "Apple \n" +
                "Banana \n" +
                "Watermelon \n" +
            "Sports \n" +
                "Soccer \n" +
                "Volleyball \n";
```

The `Str` basically has 3 categories (Animals, Fruits, Sports). Each of them in separate line. Using Regular Expression, how do I find the Fruits' contents, which will give me the output like this:

```
Apple
Banana
Watermelon
```

I would like an explanation that goes with your answer as well, so that I will have a better understand about this problem.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Regex doesn't know what a fruit is :)

Comment: @jitendra Please explain why `\p{Fruit}+` doesn't work.

Comment: @Javier What I meant was that Regex wouldn't be able to tell that Apple is a fruit.  And, I was being satirical. If there is no marker that distinguishes category (Fruits, Sports) from normal entities, then it is likely that the implementation can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to extract the text between the word "Fruits" and the word "Sports" you could use a regular expression with a [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg).  This way, if a string matches then you still have to extract the [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)) that contains the text that you want.

For example:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Fruits(.*?)Sports", Pattern.DOTALL);
// The string "Fruits" ------^     ^    ^        ^
// Capture everything in between --^    ^        ^
// The string "Sports" -----------------^        ^
// This tells the regex to treat newlines        ^
//   like normal characters ---------------------^
```

See the [railroad diagram](http://regexplained.co.uk/#eyJwYXR0ZXJuIjoiRnJ1aXRzKC4qPylTcG9ydHMifQ==) below:

[image: a railroad diagram of the image]

Alternatively, you can use a more advanced regular expression using [positive lookahead and lookbehinds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special).  This means that you can make your regular expression still look for text between the words "Fruit" and "Sports" but not consider those strings themselves as part of the match.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!Fruits).*?(?=Sports)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is by far the best response I have received. I think I have understood the concept now.:)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by splitting the string into an array of words (`String[] words = Regex.Split(Str, "\n");`), then loop through the `words` array, adding elements to their proper categories as you go along, switching between the categories as you see headings.